# django change admin view (without model)

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I want to change the admin view to perform some tasks that do not have a relation with a model (my application doesn't have a model) but it necessitates an admin to do these tasks.

I want to remove the table that allows the creation of admins and users, and fill the view with other tasks.

Can I do that? And how? (I'm new in Django).

Answer (score 0):

I presume you want use admin template according to you so that you can render stuff you want like charts, analytics or some form, Right?
I too had this problem but i solved it by **Extending Admin/Index.html**

Where you can Manipulate admin according to your needs with or without using models generated by django.

Thus, giving you the ability to create your own admin/index.html which will become your default template for the admin app. To give you the basic idea have a look at this code which allows to make your own admin/Index.html page, hence overriding the default one.

```
{% extends "admin:admin/index.html" %}

{% block sidebar %}
    {{block.super}}
  <div>
    <h1>Extra links</h1>
    <a href="/admin/extra/">My extra link</a>
  </div>
{% endblock %}
```

You can learn more here at this [blog](http://heyman.info/2011/jul/5/extending-templates-specific-django-app/) as i did.

Refer to this Django documentation [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/admin/#admin-overriding-templates) for complete information.

Comment: I tried the two links but I had no modification, is there some configuration that i had missed?

Comment: Do you get any error? can you specify it in your question. Also, do you have your code hosted somewhere, so that i can have a look.